# How to force jboss as 7 to serve https using TLS 1.0?

Tags: ssl, spring-security, jboss7.x

How do I force JBoss AS 7 to serve HTTPS content over TLS 1.0?

I am providing a Java application that uses Spring Security 3 to clients.  It is hosted on JBoss AS 7.  It can only be reached over a VPN, so I'm not too concerned with encryption at the application or transport layer.  (Perhaps I should be?)  When my users try to connect, browsers refuse the connection unless the user explicitly enables TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2.  Since my users aren't interested in these nuances, I would like to force JBoss to revert back to TLS 1.0.

How do I force JBoss AS 7 to serve HTTPS content over TLS 1.0?

My web domain setup is as follows:

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host">
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
            <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" enable-lookups="false" secure="true">
            <ssl password="myPassword" certificate-key-file="myKeyFile.jks" protocol="TLSv1" verify-client="false" certificate-file="myCertFile"/>
        </connector>
```

My socket binding group is set up as follows:

```
    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
        ....
    </socket-binding-group>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/config/ssl.html

You can force TLS by making use of the `protocol` attribute.

```
The version of the SSL protocol to use. If not specified, Supported values: SSLv2, SSLv3, TLSv1, SSLv2+SSLv3 and ALL. the default is "ALL".
```

Comment: So I replace  protocol="HTTP/1.1" in the above code with protocol "TLSv1" ?

Comment: No, the protocol="TLSv1" attribute you have in ssl element is sufficient. The one thing lacking is providing a redirect-port="443" on the http element. This combined with the web.xml security-constraint will ensure that if a client / browser connects on 80, the http connector will redirect to port 443 and the TLSV1 "security protocol" will be applied.

Comment: i.e., this?:
<socket-binding name="http" port="8080" redirect-port="8443"/>

Comment: <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" redirect-port="8443"/>